# How to differentiate between two types of coordinates in a single .txt file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a `.txt` file containing lines with 2D coordinates, followed by a color indicator, in the following format:

```
x    y   i
1    0   1
1    1   0
...
```

I want to plot the points on a single graph, those with different `i` in a different colour (`i` takes only two values). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `linecolor variable` and include the column into the `using` clause:

```
plot "file.txt" using 1:2:3 with points linecolor variable
```